# "UnicodeDecodeError" running infer_detections script

Tags: tensorflow

Running the [infer_detections script](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/inference/infer_detections.py) with my frozen graph and test set in the following way:

```
python -m infer_detections --input_tfrecord_paths=../data/coco_testdev.record --output_tfrecord_path=../data/inference --inference_graph=../model/fine_tuned_model/frozen_inference_graph.pb --discard_image_pixels
```

throws the error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 394: invalid start byte`.

The complete stack trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\GitHub\TransferLearningWithTensorflowAPI\scripts\infer_detections.py", line 96, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 124, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\GitHub\TransferLearningWithTensorflowAPI\scripts\infer_detections.py", line 74, in main
    image_tensor, FLAGS.inference_graph)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg\object_detection\inference\detection_inference.py", line 69, in build_inference_graph
    graph_content = graph_def_file.read()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 126, in read
    pywrap_tensorflow.ReadFromStream(self._read_buf, length, status))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 94, in _prepare_value
    return compat.as_str_any(val)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\compat.py", line 106, in as_str_any
    return as_str(value)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\compat.py", line 84, in as_text
    return bytes_or_text.decode(encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 394: invalid start byte
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I am facing the same. Did you manage to resolve this

Comment: No. Even worse: The Github ticket I have created at https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3903 has pretty much been abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

Change (lines 68-69 under object_detection/inference/detection_inference.py )

```
with tf.gfile.Open(inference_graph_path, 'r') as graph_def_file:
    graph_content = graph_def_file.read()
```

to

```
with tf.gfile.Open(inference_graph_path, 'rb') as graph_def_file:
    graph_content = graph_def_file.read()
```